Azure WebPubSub behind YARP proxy cannot start websocket
I've created an Azure WebPubSub service. I also have a ASP.NET Core 8 application that includes YARP. I want to proxy the websocket clients over the reverse proxy to Azure WebPubSub. I'm generating the client accesuri in my ASP.NET Core application and setting it on the requesturi. The websocket however fails to get started and a 502 is returned.
If I use the generated client access uri directly the websocket starts in the browser and can be used so it seems to be Yarp related. If I enable tracing in Azure WebPubSub no requests are logged. They are logged when I use the generated access uri directly.
The Yarp documentation claims it should just work but I fail to find any pointers since I cannot find a proper error.
 transformContext.ProxyRequest.RequestUri = await webPubSubServiceClient.GetClientAccessUriAsync(expiresAt, userId, cancellationToken: cancellationToken)



In the log, I see HTTP/1.1 RequestVersionOrLower. WebSockets typically require an HTTP/1.1 connection with an Upgrade header, but if something blocks the upgrade (like a misconfiguration), the connection can fail.


The websocket however fails to get started and a 502 is returned.

The above error mostly comes when we misconfigure the endpoint in the appsetting.json file. Even I also go the same error at first.
program.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebPubSub.AspNetCore;
using Azure.Messaging.WebPubSub;
using System;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Load configuration
builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

// Add services
builder.Services.AddReverseProxy()
    .LoadFromConfig(builder.Configuration.GetSection("ReverseProxy"));

// Register the Web PubSub service client
builder.Services.AddSingleton<WebPubSubServiceClient>(provider =>
{
    // Replace with your connection string
    string connectionString = builder.Configuration["WebPubSub:ConnectionString"];
    return new WebPubSubServiceClient(connectionString);
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Middleware to transform requests
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/client"))
    {
        var webPubSubServiceClient = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<WebPubSubServiceClient>();
        
        // Generate the client access URI
        string hubName = "your_hub_name"; // Replace with your hub name
        var accessUri = await webPubSubServiceClient.GetClientAccessUriAsync(hubName);
        
        // Transform the request URI to the Web PubSub client access URI
        context.Request.Headers.Remove("Host"); // Optionally remove Host header
        context.Request.Path = accessUri.PathAndQuery; // Update the path to the access URI
    }
    await next();
});

// Configure routing
app.UseRouting();

// Configure endpoints
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapReverseProxy();
});

// Run the application
app.Run();

Here, below you can check appsettings.json file.
  "Azure": {
    "WebPubSub": {
      "ConnectionString": "Endpoint=https://newpubsub.webpubsub.azure.com;AccessKey=AiQ0HbXx1Zk6RkhvcaMevcX+VRRT8Fbz4u+ixv8feZc=;Version=1.0;"
    }
  },
  "ReverseProxy": {
    "Routes": {
      "webpubsub": {
        "ClusterId": "webpubsubcluster",
        "Match": {
          "Path": "/webpubsub/{**catchAll}"
        },
        "Transforms": [
          {
            "RequestHeader": "X-Forwarded-Host",
            "Append": "true"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "Clusters": {
      "webpubsubcluster": {
        "Destinations": {
          "webpubsub": {
            "Address": "https://newpubsub.webpubsub.azure.com"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}

Successfully proxying WebSocket connections.

info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5044
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\Users\..\Dotnet_projects\WebProxyApp
info: Yarp.ReverseProxy.Configuration.ConfigProvider.ConfigurationConfigProvider[1]
      Loading proxy data from config.
info: Yarp.ReverseProxy.Configuration.ConfigProvider.ConfigurationConfigProvider[1]
      Successfully loaded proxy configuration.
info: Microsoft.Azure.WebPubSub.AspNetCore.WebPubSubService[0]
      Web PubSub service endpoint is configured.
info: Microsoft.Azure.WebPubSub.AspNetCore.WebPubSubService[0]
      Client access URI service initialized for hub: your-hub-name
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware[0]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5044/generateClientAccessUri
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]
      Executing endpoint "WebProxyApp.Program+<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<Main>b__1"
info: Microsoft.Azure.WebPubSub.AspNetCore.WebPubSubService[0]
      Generating client access URI for hub: your-hub-name
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]
      Executed endpoint "WebProxyApp.Program+<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<Main>b__1"
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 20.2515ms 200 application/json; charset=utf-8

